# Requests from Swagger UI bypassing Spring Cloud API Gateway and directly accessing individual services

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, swagger-ui, openapi, api-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud API Gateway with Swagger to manage my microservices endpoints at a centralized place (API gateway). However, when I hit the endpoints from Swagger UI, the requests are not being routed through the API Gateway, and instead are being accessed directly in the individual services.

My configuration is as follows:

1. Springboot Version 3.0.2
2. Spring Cloud Version 2022.0.0
3. Java Version 17

***My Swagger configuration includes:***

**API gateway configuration**

1. Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Swagger configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Autowired
    RouteDefinitionLocator locator;

    private static final String API_URI = "/v3/api-docs";

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi apis(SwaggerUiConfigProperties swaggerUiConfigProperties) {

        Set<AbstractSwaggerUiConfigProperties.SwaggerUrl> urls = new HashSet<>();
        locator.getRouteDefinitions().subscribe(routeDefinition -> {
            String resourceName = routeDefinition.getId();
            if (resourceName.contains("-SERVICE")) {
                String location = routeDefinition.getPredicates()
                        .get(0)
                        .getArgs()
                        .get("pattern")
                        .replace("/**", API_URI);
                String displayName = resourceName.replace("ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_", "");
                urls.add(new AbstractSwaggerUiConfigProperties.SwaggerUrl(resourceName, location, displayName));
            }
        });

        swaggerUiConfigProperties.setUrls(urls);

        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("resource")
                .pathsToMatch("/api/**")
                .build();
    }
```

3. in `application.properties`

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
```

This is done to tackle the CORS failure error

**Configuration on individual services**

1. Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Code to handle CORS failure error

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Did you find solution about question? I have same problem with you